# Query on Jmeter +JSON

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How can i create a JSON file that contain the below data in Bean shell Scripting and call every iteration on Jmeter

```
{
    "1436327282123": {
        "NumCopies": 20,
        "Status": "done printing",
        "Title": "demo.jpg",
        "Username": "David",
        "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
        "print status": "OK",
        "time": "1429036296",
        "timestampDonePrintingAttr": 1436327282
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use beanshell here ? what is variable in your request, can you clarify your question ?

Comment: I need to Create a JSON file as such in Jmeter and upload the file created  with HTTP  multipart request in Jmeter , this the only way i found to do it from Jmeter.Each requets should have "timestampDonePrintingAttr" as a unique parameter and with 1436327282123 as a unique id